# Remove Archive Posts Page

Tags: posts, archives

i have  a route  by year like this
x.com/2022
and it includes blogs for 2022 year  -that's in addition to the original blogs page-
but i wanna remove it because i wanna put another page on the route it archives on , but i don't know how or why even it was made in the first place.

and i searched in the pages  but i didn't find it
and also the permalinks is chosen to be postname.

Theme i use : exhibz

**Question** : How can i find this route and remove it or even disable or change it ?